# kendo UI dropdown control not showing all the values in the collection

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have implemented around 6 kendo dropdown controls in my angular 7 application which was initially working and now suddenly stopped working. The control markup looks fine to me.  I can see also see the collection for the dropdown containing values. Not sure why I all the values are not getting bound to the control. Only the value that matched the ID is shown in the control. The control does open on selection and can't see the rest of the values while inspecting the element. Do I need to create an original list before the data is bound to control and then rebind the original list back to the control when the user selects. Neither can i see any errors.

Data for one the dropdown control (FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses)

```
[{
    "RANK_ORDER":20,
    "NAME":"Illiquid",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":20,
    "ID":134,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2018-06-13T09:07:09",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2018-06-13T09:07:09",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":96,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":96
}, {
    "RANK_ORDER":1,
    "NAME":"Invested",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":1,
    "ID":1,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2014-02-04T12:50:20",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2014-10-23T22:56:37",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":52,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":338
}, {
    "RANK_ORDER":9,
    "NAME":"Not Evaluated",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":4,
    "ID":9,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2014-02-12T10:10:39",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2018-08-22T10:49:48",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":52,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":96
}, {
    "RANK_ORDER":4,
    "NAME":"Prospective",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":3,
    "ID":6,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2014-02-04T12:50:20",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2018-08-22T10:49:50",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":52,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":96
}, {
    "RANK_ORDER":8,
    "NAME":"Prospective - Inactive",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":7,
    "ID":8,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2014-02-04T12:50:20",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2018-08-22T10:49:50",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":52,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":96
}, {
    "RANK_ORDER":7,
    "NAME":"Redeemed",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":11,
    "ID":106,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2014-09-09T18:51:12",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2014-10-23T22:56:38",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":338,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":338
}, {
    "RANK_ORDER":2,
    "NAME":"Redeeming",
    "IS_ACTIVE":true,
    "SORT_ORDER":5,
    "ID":4,
    "DATE_CREATED":"2014-02-04T12:50:20",
    "LAST_MODIFIED":"2014-10-23T22:56:37",
    "CREATED_BY_ID":52,
    "LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID":338
}]
```

Markup

```
      <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-form-label ">Investment Status</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails?.InvestmentStatusName}}</div>
           <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatusId"
                        class="form-control form-control-sm" [data]="FundDetails.InvestmentStatuses"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="NAME" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="ID">
          </kendo-dropdownlist>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Component code

```
getFundDetails(selectedFundId: number) {
        // Initialize fundid to 0 to test new fund
        // selectedFundId = 0;

        if (selectedFundId != null) {
            this.fundService.getFundDetails(selectedFundId).subscribe((data: IFund[]) => {
                // data.forEach((d) => {d.InceptionDate = new Date(d.InceptionDate); });
                this.FundDetails = data;
                this.OriginalFundStrategiesList = this.FundDetails.FundStrategies;
                this.SelectedFundId = this.FundDetails.FundId;

                // if ( this.SelectedFundId === 0) {
                //     this.resetForm();
                // }
            });
        }
    }
```

Interface

```
export interface IFund {
    FundId: number;
    FundName: string;
    IsAnonymous: boolean;
    BloombergTicker: string;
    InvestmentStatusId: number;
    InvestmentStatusName: string;
    FlagShipFundId: number;
    InceptionDate: Date;
    AccountMandateId: number;
    AccountMandateName: string;
    VehicleTypeId: number;
    VehicleTypeName: string;
    PrimaryClassId: number;
    PrimaryClassDescripton: string;
}
```

I have even tried using the native properties of the kendo drop down but no luck

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist  k-ng-model="FundDetails.VehicleTypeId"
                    k-data-text-field="'NAME'"
                    k-value-primitive="true"                
                    k-data-value-field="ID"
                    k-data-source="FundDetails.VehicleTypes">

                </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

The latest update is, I commented out all dropdown boxes and just left one on the screen. I can see the dropdown rendering but its behind the UI. So what I understand is the values are getting correctly bound but hidden in the UI for some reason

[image]

Comment: Try adding `private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef` to your constructor and then calling `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` after `this.SelectedFundId = this.FundDetails.FundId;`.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved as my css class was the main culprit.

//z-index: 10050 !important;